# $rootScope $broadcast working on two different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a single page application where I have a setting form where I add a variable called Ticket Work type. When I do an update or save on the setting form, I am broadcasting the new Ticket Work Type array so that it reflects the listing as well as Ticket create page.

But the problem is that broadcast works only on the settings form page controller and not on the Ticket Add controller.

This is the code from the Settings controller where after "addTicketWorkTypes" factory method, I do a broadcast. This works :

```
$scope.addNewTicketWorkType = function(newticketWorkType) {
  if (newticketWorkType != '') {
    ticketFact.addTicketWorkTypes(newticketWorkType, $scope.workspaceId).then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleTicketWorkType',response.data);
    ticketFact.ticketWorkType = '';
  });
 }
};
```

And this updates the list on the same controller

```
/*update ticket work type when changes at any place*/
  $scope.$on('handleTicketWorkType', function(events, ticketWorkType) {
    $scope.ticketWorkType = ticketWorkType;
    console.log('Scope updated settingsEditCtrl');
  });
```

But the same $scope.$on doesn't work on a different controller. Can you please help.

The whole code is on Github for reference as well:
The settings controller is here: https://github.com/amitavroy/my-pm-tools/blob/master/public/assets/js/dev/settings/controllers/settingsEditCtrl.js

and the Ticket Add screen controller is here: https://github.com/amitavroy/my-pm-tools/blob/master/public/assets/js/dev/tickets/controllers/ticketAddCtrl.js

Comment: sounds like controller is not available when you do the broadcast and you may need to use a service to store the data

Answer (score 1):

Any given scope will only be notified of events that are broadcast from a scope higher in the inheritance hierarchy. To send an event up the hierarchy use `$rootScope.$emit()`.

If you want to be sure the event will be sent and received and you're not worried about other scopes responding to the event, you can do this:

```
function $broadcast() {
        return $rootScope.$broadcast.apply($rootScope, arguments);
    }
```

...

```
$broadcast('handleTicketWorkType', response.data);
```

In your other controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('handleTicketWorkType', function(data) {...});
```

### If that doesn't work

It must be (as suggested by @charlietfl) that the target $scope does not yet exist and is hence not being notified of the event. In that case create a `ticketWorkTypes` service that is nothing but a list of `ticketWorkTypes`. Then replace:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('handleTicketWorkType',response.data);
```

with

```
ticketWorkTypes.push(response.data);
```

Then inject ticketWorkTypes service (array) into any controller that needs that data.

Comment: `$broadcast` can be watched by all descendent scopes that are available at the time. I can't see what difference it makes using `$scope.$on` and not need to inject `$rootScope`

Comment: Agree there should be a better way, but this option at least confirms the target scope exists at the time of broadcast.

Comment: Well I tried this approach, but again the function is not getting called from the Ticket Add page. And about the hierarchy, both are different routes and so I don't think hierarchy is a problem. :(